# block access to wrt from vlan using iptables dd-wrt

Tags: iptables, router

I set up multiple isolated vlans in dd-wrt. Now I need to forward a port to vlan2.

I isolated the vlans using:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o vlan2 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o vlan3 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o vlan4 -j DROP
```

Now I need to block a clients on each vlan from accessing the router.

This doesn't work:

```
iptables -I INPUT -i br0 -o vlan2 --dport telnet -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

I'm new it iptables... am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the client to not access **the router**, you can't use `-o`. In addition, if you want to use `--dport`, you must specify the protocol. So, do it like this:

```
iptables -I INPUT -i br0 -p tcp --dport telnet -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

`-o` is used only if you want to apply the rule to a packet *passing* the router.

Comment: How do I specify vlan2 with out using -0?

Comment: @NitroxDM have you tried `iptables -I INPUT -i vlan2 __rest_of_rule__` ?